# AutoMapper: What is the difference between ForMember() and ForPath()?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-6

I am reading AutoMapper's `ReverseMap()` and I can not understand the difference between `ForMember()` and `ForPath()`. Implementations was described [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening). In my experience I achieved with `ForMember()`.

See the following code where I have configured reverse mapping:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
           .ForMember(dist => dist.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Surname} {src.Name}"))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(dist => dist.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[0]))
            .ForMember(dist => dist.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[1]));
    });

    // mapping Customer -> CustomerDto            
    //... 
    //

    // mapping CustomerDto -> Customer
    var customerDto = new CustomerDto
    {
        CustomerName = "Shakhabov Adam",
        Age = 31
    };
    var newCustomer = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(customerDto);
}
```

It is working.

---

### Question

Do `ForMember` and `ForPath` the same things or when should I use `ForPath()` over `ForMember()`?

Comment: Apparently `Member` means (and accepts) direct property/field accessor, while `Path` - well, property/field path, i.e. property/field of a nested member.

Comment: @IvanStoev, why `.ForPath(dist => dist.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[0]))` and `.ForMember(dist => dist.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[0]))` have same result?

Comment: Probably because *path* is a superset of *member*. So *path* can be used in any place which expects *member*, but not (always) vice versa. In your example there is no nested object property, so both are one and the same. But if you have something like `Customer.Order.Name`, you can use `ForPath` and not `ForMember`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, to avoid inconsistencies, `ForPath` is translated internally to `ForMember`. Although what @IvanStoev says makes sense, another way to look at it is that `ForPath` is a subset of `ForMember`. Because you can do more things in `ForMember`. So when you have a member, use `ForMember` and when you have a path, use `ForPath` :)

Comment: This answer seems to state the opposite of what the docs suggest. What additional functionality is there in the `ForMember` as opposed to `ForPath`? I believe those are fundamentally the same, except the latter gets deeper into nested properties. It's mentioned on their website that about 5% of cases are the complicated ones.

Comment: It does no such thing :) Check the number of methods in the respective interfaces, there are a lot more with `ForMember`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for formulating unclear statement. They have similar outcome of the operation. As it seems in practical case, when one runs the code, the outcome of them is the same, except one gets an exception for sub-properties when applying member-version, which works using path-version. The code itself, I haven't looked at so I'll simply accept your statement at the face value. But do you say that the **functionality** of the path-version is a subset of member-version, then, or the opposite?

Comment: As intellisense shows, you can do more things in `ForMember`. But if you don't need any of that, `ForPath` will do.

Answer (score 6):

`ForMember()` can only access root-properties of the mapped object. `ForPath()` can also access its sub-properties.

In my experience they do the same thing with the one exception. If you have something like this:

```
a.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
  .ForMember(
    a => a.RootProp.SubProp, 
    b => b.MapFrom(c => c.RootProp.Get()))
```

it's going to fail producing the following error.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression 'a => a.RootProp.SubProp' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. (Parameter 'lambdaExpression')'

Because of that you need to replace `ForMember()` with `ForPath()` like so.

```
a.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
  .ForPath(
    a => a.RootProp.SubProp, 
    b => b.MapFrom(c => c.RootProp.Get()))
```

I have limited experience using [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) but it tells me that `ForPath()` has the same funcionallity as `ForMember()` (although with some extras). In usual cases we use `ForMember()` instead of `ForPath()`. I am not sure why, perhaps due to performance issues.