# How to resolve 'Nullable object must have a value' error in Automapper and EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server application in which I added a **new **nullable field called `ShippingWeek` to an entity called `OrderDetail`. However, when I try to use Automapper to map an `Order` entity to its corresponding `OrderDto` entity, I get a
`System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value` 
error. Here's the code I'm using in OnInitializedAsync:

```
IQueryable<OrderDto?> _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order);
```

And here's the relevant portion of the Automapper profile:

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.OrderDetailsDto,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderDetails))
    .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.Customer,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer))
    .ForAllMembers(opts =>
    {
        opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null);
    });
```

How can I resolve this error and use Automapper to map the two entities correctly?

**Edit:**

I also tried PreCondition but I still had the same problem.

Here are entities, simplified for brevity.

```
public class Order
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }   


}

public class OrderDto
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public List<OrderDetailDto> OrderDetailsDto { get; set; }   


}
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Currency { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public int ShippingWeek { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDetailDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Currency { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public OrderDto OrderDto { get; set; }
    public int ShippingWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping profile for OrderDetail.

```
 CreateMap<OrderDetail, OrderDetailDto>()
     .ForMember(dest =>
             dest.OrderDto,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Order))
     .ForMember(dest =>
             dest.VendorDto,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vendor))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingWeek, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ShippingWeek))
     .ForAllMembers(opts =>
     {
         opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null);
     });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you show use the mapping for the OrderDetail and its corresponding target class? At best show us the definition of the ShippingWeek property in those both classes also.

Comment: I updated my post and added the related entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForPath can solve the issue.

For the difference between ForMember() and ForPath(), [you can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524446/automapper-what-is-the-difference-between-formember-and-forpath):

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.OrderDetailsDto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderDetails))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer))
    .ForAllMembers(opts =>
    {
        opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null);
    });
```

Comment: dest.OrderDetailsDto.ShippingWeek not accessible

Comment: I saw the models later. You have written the solution. I am correcting it not to mislead others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I find a solution.

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForPath(dest =>
            dest.OrderDetailsDto,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderDetails))
    .ForMember(dest =>
            dest.Customer,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer))
    .ForAllMembers(opts =>
    {
        opts.PreCondition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null);
    });
```